# SQL Server 2000 with statement and recursive with

Tags: recursion, sql-server-2000, common-table-expression

I have a problem in SQL Server 2000. I cannot send a recursive `WITH` query because CTE was introduced in SQL Server 2005.

My question is the following:

how can I retrieve the answer of a hierarchy if I do not want to use a procedure but I can send 2 queries in which case I can include the answer of the first query in the second.

This is the query for SQL Server 2005:

```
WITH recursive_back (SOACTION,SOACTIONS) AS
(SELECT child.SOACTION,child.SOACTIONS
   FROM  soaction child
  WHERE child.soaction ={id to search}
  UNION ALL
 SELECT parent.SOACTION,parent.SOACTIONS
   FROM recursive_back child,soaction parent
  WHERE child.soactions = parent.soaction ),
recursive_ahead (SOACTION,SOACTIONS) AS
(SELECT parent.SOACTION, parent.SOACTIONS
   FROM soaction parent,recursive_back
  WHERE parent.soaction=recursive_back.soaction
  UNION ALL
 SELECT child.SOACTION, child.SOACTIONS
   FROM recursive_ahead parent, soaction child
  WHERE child.soactions = parent.soaction)

SELECT R.SOACTION,R.SOACTIONS
  FROM recursive_back R, SOACTION A
 WHERE R.SOACTION=A.SOACTION
 UNION
SELECT R.SOACTION,R.SOACTIONS
  FROM recursive_ahead R, SOACTION A
 WHERE R.SOACTION=A.SOACTION;

GO
```

Comment: Sorry for being off-topic, but why would you need to port back to SQL 2000?

Comment: Easiest solution: **upgrade!** Seriously - even SQL Server 2005 is already "out of regular support" with Microsoft.

Comment: One way of getting recursion in SQL Server 2000 is to have a Table Valued Function that calls itself recursively.

Comment: The system is ERP and must have cross compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I cannot use function or procedure because the query is generic and can reprecent any hierarchy in the database. It would not be a good way to go if I created a procedure or function for every query of this kind.

Comment: What do you mean the query is generic? It accesses specific objects doesn't it? Trying to write catch all generic code in SQL Server is usually a mistake just write efficient code against specific objects.

Comment: I mean that query like that (different queries same logic) which is quite efficiate is used in varius parts of the code base. Imagine if I created 10 procedures for sql server another 10 for oracle etc. The db would become complicated and we would have to add procedures for new queries in the same logic. If there was a query or combination of queries that could solve that issue would be the best. It would be efficient in our case because we have a framework in which we can send multiple queries reducing the communication cost.